# onended() does not fire in Safari or on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webkit, web-audio-api

The following code works on Chrome 80.0 and Firefox 74.0 (OSX 10.14.6). However, on OSX Safari 13.0.5 or on iOS (testing in Chrome, Safari), the `<div>` element never turns blue, indicating that the `onended` callback does not fire. Is this a bug?

```js
const ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

const buff = ctx.createBuffer(1, 32, ctx.sampleRate);
const buffSource = ctx.createBufferSource();
buffSource.buffer = buff;
buffSource.loop = false;

// attempt to add an event listener to the buffer source
buffSource.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';    
});

// another slight variation using the named function
function changeBackground() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';    
}
buffSource.addEventListener('ended', changeBackground);

// the documentation suggestion modifying the function directly
buffSource.onended = function(){
    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};

// maybe binding would help?
buffSource.onended = function(){
    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}.bind(this);

document.getElementById('button').onclick = (e) => {
    ctx.resume();
    buffSource.start();
    document.getElementById('message').innerText = "Pressed Button";
};
```

```css
#test {
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
#button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <button id = 'button'>Click me</button>
  <div id = 'test'></div>
  <div id = 'message'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari doesn't fire the `ended` event if the `AudioBufferSourceNode` is not connected.

```
buffSource.connect(ctx.destination);
```

Executing this line before calling `start()` should make it work.

Comment: Thanks, it works! So simple, yet I couldn't find this piece of information anywhere else.